# Error when compiling file | collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I am having a lot of problem and can't seem to make any sense of what is going on. I am trying to learn C from [Learn C The Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/), and I am trying to compile the [first exercise](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex1.html). When ever I run make I get a huge problem

```
cc     ex1.c   -o ex1

ex1.c: In function ‘main’:

ex1.c:3:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘put’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

     put("Hello world.");
     ^

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/../../../libc.so when searching for -lc

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libc.so when searching for -lc

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libc.so when searching for -lc

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

<builtin>: recipe for target 'ex1' failed


make: *** [ex1] Error 1
```

any help would be wonderful

Comment: `put()` --> `puts()`.

Comment: The implicit declaration warning means that the compiler can't find the function named "put" anyplace, and is going to try and make one up for you.  This is usually bad since the one that it makes up is almost never correct.  Sometimes you have just typed the name wrong, like in your case.  As the others mention, you typed "put" instead of "puts".

Comment: @bruceg : Even then, if you look at the exercise at http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex1.html, you can see that the author has omitted the stdio.h header file deliberately to force this warning.  Not a teaching style I think makes much sense - especially as he does not go on to explain how to fix it, or why it matters.

Comment: "/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libc.so when searching for -lc" - this is highly unusual and likely a major problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is clear; there is no declaration for a function called `put()`.  This is either because

- you have mistyped the function name,
- or because you have failed to provide a declaration either directly of via a header file containing the declaration.

In this case if the code you were attempting to compile is from [this exercise](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex1.html) then look at it again - it clearly differs from your code (i.e. the first of the possibilities listed above).  However even then you would get the same error; read further in the exercise and you will see that the author has deliberately omitted the header file in order to illustrate the need for the specific library header file.  The reason you get the warning without the suggested `-Wall` command line option is probably because you are using a newer version of the compiler than the author.  To be honest from what little I have seen of "Learn C the Hard Way", I would steer clear of it.

The second issue is one of your linker being unable to find an appropriate version of the standard C library to link to your code.  Compiling C code in Linux is normally straightforward; most distributions come with GCC already correctly installed and working; your's appears to be horribly broken.  You may want to repair your toolchain installation.  You may have installed multiple incompatible toolchains.